# Delete label using Gmail API Python

Tags: python, gmail-api

**Trying to use Gmail API to delete a label**. But it doesn't seem to be working and triggering an **insufficient permission** error in python. It doesn't seem correct because in google shows all permissions checked off. Is there a code fix that I can apply to resolve or is it something else?

**CODE USED TO DELETE LABEL**

```
try:
            target_label_name = "Label_8"
            service = build("gmail", "v1", credentials=creds)
            messages_results = service.users().messages().list(userId="me", labelIds=[target_label_name]).execute()
            messages = messages_results.get("messages", [])
    
            if not messages:
                print(f"No emails found with label: {target_label_name}")
                return
    
            for message in messages:
                # Remove the label from the message
                service.users().messages().modify(userId="me", id=message['id'], body={'removeLabelIds': [target_label_name]}).execute()
                print(f"Label {target_label_name} removed from message {message['id']}.")
```

**Get this error about insufficient permissions**

<HttpError 403 when requesting https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/18c8dae6ea7e602e/modify?alt=json returned "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.". Details: "[{'message': 'Insufficient Permission', 'domain': 'global', 'reason': 'insufficientPermissions'}]">

**But Google Console Shows I have all permissions**

[image]

**FULL CODE**

```
import os.path
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError

SCOPES = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify"]

def main():
    creds = None
    credentials_path = "C:\\credentials1.json"

    if os.path.exists("token.json"):
        creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file("token.json", SCOPES)

    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                credentials_path, SCOPES
            )
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        with open("token.json", "w") as token:
            token.write(creds.to_json())

    try:
        target_label_name = "Label_8"
        service = build("gmail", "v1", credentials=creds)
        messages_results = service.users().messages().list(userId="me", labelIds=[target_label_name]).execute()
        messages = messages_results.get("messages", [])

        if not messages:
            print(f"No emails found with label: {target_label_name}")
            return

        for message in messages:
            # Remove the label from the message
            service.users().messages().modify(userId="me", id=message['id'], body={'removeLabelIds': [target_label_name]}).execute()
            print(f"Label {target_label_name} removed from message {message['id']}.")

    except HttpError as error:
        print(f"An error occurred: {error}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**MAYBE RELATED TO SCOPES IN OAUTH CONSENT SCREEN**
[image]

Comment: "*Google Console Shows I have all permissions*" The screenshot you provided does **not** show this. The tab you've selected in the screenshot is "Metrics" and provides a visualization of your usage of these APIs. It alone has absolutely no bearing on the actual permissions you have assigned.

Comment: You have a pretty glaring inconsistency in your code; can you clarify if your credentials for this service should be in `C:\credentials1.json` or `token.json`? You're referencing them both interchangeably; I'm skeptical of the correctness of this setup.

Comment: def main():
    creds = None
    credentials_path = "C:\\...\\credentials1.json"

    if os.path.exists("token.json"):
        creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file("token.json", SCOPES) WORKS in another component where I read and exract data. I didnt represent that particular component exactly as it appears. Also, I changed the name of the actual label for simplicity. I think this is not the problem.

Comment: It could very well be the problem if the credentials in `token.json` file are not the ones authorized to use the required scope to perform this action.

Comment: @esqew. I have no clue about the permissions assigned. In IAM I am owner

Comment: I do note that I dont have any options to define scopes inside of the oauth consent screen.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256367/discussion-between-mmsmithh-and-esqew).

Comment: Have you tried to add this scope on your code: 

[https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.labels](https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.labels) ?

Comment: Please leave you're code in the question its Relevant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete token.json and run approve the authorization again.   You changed the scope without requesting access again for the new scope

Comment: I think this is right. Working on it now.

Comment: It should be you are using the correct scope in your code now

Comment: Yes. I actually  started working on this just before I saw your answer because I suspected based on the convo with @esqew that the code was not the problem. I thought could be the console setup, since auth setup never asked for specific scopes (that I noticed) so after setting up again, that is what I did & also realized token.json was not being saved to the same folder, which is how I missed this as the error. Thanks.